# iis 7.5 - WFF and ARR farm management

Tags: iis-7.5, nlb, arr, web-farm

We have two test web farms (IIS 7.5). The Florida web farm has two ARR servers and two content servers. The ARR servers have WFF and NLB installed. The ARR setup uses a shared config located on a file share. The content servers do not have WFF installed. There is one web farm, and it's managed on an ARR server.

The Illinois web farm also has two ARR servers and two content servers. ARR servers have WFF and NLB installed, and they use a shared config located on a share. One of the content servers has WFF installed, which makes it the controller; it's also the primary content server.

Apparently, Illinois isn't properly configured. From what we've pieced together from various IIS.net articles and this post (http://ruslany.net/2010/07/web-farm-framework-2-0-overview/), the controller should be one of the ARR servers (like our Florida setup).

The thing is Florida's controller doesn't have a Primary server nor can you set one of the content servers as Primary. It doesn't have the management piece showing the Trace messages when you click the Servers node (from iis console, Server Farms/FLFarm/Servers http://ruslany.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/WebFarm8.png).

That management piece does exist in the Illinois farm, but that's a bad configuration.

What are we missing that our Florida configuration doesn't have the Primary and Secondary content servers, and the management piece? I have looked for IIS role differences, but there are none.